# How to specify a port number while running flutter web

Tags: flutter-web

Is there any way to start Flutter web, with a Headless-Server target, always on the same specified port number ?

Today, running the web application with:

```
flutter run -d headless-server
```

Provides a random port number.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I found the answer inside the flutter_tools source code:

```
flutter run -d headless-server --web-port=1234
```

Comment: strange this is still not listed when you do "flutter run -h"

Comment: or `flutter run -d chrome --web-port=1234`

Answer (score 86):

To do this for Android Studio, just add the additional parameters to menu `Run` > `Edit configuration`. So in the `Additional arguments`, add `--web-port=49430`

[image: Menu Edit configurations]

[image: Update arguments]

Comment: Where is this in Android Studio?

Comment: @giorgio79 open de dropdown voor run configurations (next to the device selection dropdown) and select `Edit Configurations`

Comment: How to do it on VSCODE?

Comment: For VSCODE you can add a port to use as argument in launch.json config file.  See here... https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/1769#issuecomment-552982008

Answer (score 74):

The above solution works fine if you are like using command line. But if you you are using VsCode by `CTRL+F5` that won't work. So to make vscode `CTRL+F5` run in chrome or web-server go to your project root directory create `.vscode` directory and inside that folder add `launch.json` file.

Now if you want to run in web server add this lines in you `launch.json`

```
{
 "version": "0.2.0",
 "configurations": [{
        "name": "Flutter",
        "request": "launch",
        "type": "dart",
        "args": ["-d", "web-server","--web-port", "8000"],
    }
]}
```

And if you want to launch in chrome device change argument `web-server` to `chome` i.e.

```
{   
 "version": "0.2.0",
 "configurations": [{
        "name": "Flutter",
        "request": "launch",
        "type": "dart",
        "args": ["-d", "chrome","--web-port", "8000"],
    }
]}
```

Now run `CTRL+F5`

Comment: Can you share how to do the same for Android Studio?

Comment: @SlickSlime check my response here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63808434/969016

Comment: see here for detail on the vscode config settings used by @eli https://dartcode.org/docs/launch-configuration/

Comment: Just what I was looking for.

Comment: Did not work until I added also `"program": "lib/main.dart",`

Comment: Where should I put this `launch.json` file?  I tried to create `launch.json` file beside `pubspec.yaml` but didn't work!

Comment: @WDR Read my instruction above. So to make vscode CTRL+F5 run in chrome or web-server go to your project root directory create .vscode directory and inside that folder add launch.json file.

Answer (score 30):

You can run flutter web on any chromium based browser

```
Chrome     |    Edge
```

**Use any one to launch flutter web application with custom port**

```
flutter run -d chrome --web-port 5555

flutter run -d edge --web-port 5555

flutter run -d web-server --web-port 5555
```

---

**EDIT**

**UNRELATED TO THE MAIN Question, but Helpful if you face the below-mentioned issue.**

Recently faced an issue with a flutter web application, it was not running and no logs/ errors were visible.

How I fixed it.

Run `flutter build web`
this should print out the errors, fix those errors and then try running your application by above mentioned commands

Comment: Maybe its just a macOS thing?  Seems like I need "web" not "web-server", it doesn't launch the same but does start: `flutter -v run  -d web --web-port=28080`  Still, --web-port is the trick here. :)

Answer (score 6):

This works well too -

```
flutter run -d web-server --web-port 8080
```

Answer (score 5):

**Solution for VS Code**

1. Go to settings
2. Search for `Dart: Flutter Run Additional Args`
3. Enter `--web-port=1234`
4. Click `Add Item`

[image: VS Code setting to set up flutter web port]