# How can I load the previous signed in user?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter-web

In my application, I happen to have two types of users, hospital, and patients, both are configured to use the same authentication by firebase. What I would like to know is, how do I load the page for the respective user depending on how they were signed in previously? For example, if a hospital had signed in and not logged out, when they run the app, it should display the hospitals' dashboard and not the patients'. How do I configure this?

Answer (score 0):

`shared_prefs` supports Flutter web. Save a value stating the account type.

See this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59579821/13714686

```dart
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
bool isHospital = (prefs.getBool('isHospitalAccount');
if(isHospital == true){
 //hospital navigation 
}
else{
  //patient navigation 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to check whether the user is logged in or not. For this, you can check through the below code.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget{

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context){
        return FutureBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
            future: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<FirebaseUser> snapshot){
                       if (snapshot.hasData){
                           FirebaseUser user = snapshot.data; // this is your user 

                           /// is because there is a user already logged, So route them to a Screen of Dashboard directly.
                           
                           return MainScreen();
                        }
                         /// other way there is no user logged.
                         return LoginScreen();
             }
          );
    }
}
```

Now, you need to maintain a list of users in FireStore where the user's metadata like the last login, User Type information will be stored. Using this information you can Route the user accordingly.