# Optimal way to retain user session on Flutter Web and Supabase

Tags: flutter, supabase, supabase-flutter

I'm creating a web-app with Flutter and using Supabase to handle authentication.

However, when I close the browser, my logged in session is not persistent when I start the app up again. (Logging in works fine and remains as long as I don't close the browser)

I read from the [supabase_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/supabase_flutter#custom-localstorage) package that it uses Hive by default to persist the user session.

Does that only work on mobile or is there something else I should be considering when trying to retain a logged in session on Flutter Web?

This is my code that is ran when the app starts in a home screen initState after initializing Supabase (and the code redirects me to 'login' since the session is null when starting the app every time)

```dart
/// Load auth session
Future.wait([
  SupabaseAuth.instance.initialSession,
  Future.delayed(
    const Duration(milliseconds: 2000), // Animation
  ),
]).then((responseList) {
  final session = responseList.first as Session?;
  session != null ? context.goNamed('watch') : context.goNamed('login');
}).catchError((_) {
   debugPrint('Initial session loading failed!');
});
```

I've seen some posts online talking about using `shared_preferences` but I think that was only intended for mobile builds and before Hive was implemented (also that it's not secure enough for this kind of task).

**EDIT:**

This is how I initialize Supabase in my `main.dart`

```dart
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Supabase.initialize(
    url: 'https://<placeholder>.supabase.co',
    anonKey: <placeholder>,
  );
  debugPrint("App initialized");
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

I use GoRouter for navigation and set a `home.dart` as my initial 'splash screen' to navigate to either a 'watch' page or 'login' page depending on if the session is null:

```dart
 Future<void> _redirect() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration.zero);
    if (!mounted) {
      return;
    }

    final session = supabase.auth.currentSession;
    if (session != null) {
      context.goNamed('watch');
    } else {
      debugPrint("Session was NULL");
      context.goNamed('login');
    }
  }
```

And indeed if I login and enter the root URL in the address bar or refresh the browser, I get redirected to the 'watch' page as intended.
However if I close the browser and restart the debug session, I get redirected to the login page and receive the "Session was NULL" debug print.

Answer (score 1):

supabase_flutter should persist your session on Flutter web without any special configuration.

No need to use `SupabaseAuth.initialSession` now. You can just use the `currentSession` to reliably see if the user is signed in or not.

```dart
final Session? session = Supabase.instance.client.auth.currentSession;
if(session == null) {
  // not signed in
} else {
  // signed in
}
```

If this does not work for you, there might be something weird going on with either where you call `Supabase.initialize()` or the sign in code. If you could share them, we would be able to further assist you.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your comment Tyler, it definitely eases my mind a bit that it _should_ work, so I definitely should keep testing instead of looking for a different, more complex solution. 
I added some more context in the opening post, but I doubt you would get much out of it. I didn't add the login code because it's simply just ```await supabase.auth.signInWithPassword(email, pw)``` from a form submit.

Comment: Turns out the issue was due to me always running my app through the VSCode browser/debugger, which cleared out everything. Once I built the web app and hosted it on a local python server, the session retained just fine. This is probably such common knowledge for most developers, which is why I never encountered it while researching this issue.

Comment: @liquardo Ah, I see. It's probably because Flutter web launches on a different local host every time you run it. If you specify what port to use, the session will be persisted with the VS Code debugger as well!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58248277/how-to-specify-a-port-number-while-running-flutter-web

Comment: You are absolutely correct, that did the trick even in debug-mode! Thank you so much!