# Start Dart VM on a specific local port to avoid SMS confirmation

Tags: flutter, dart

Here's a snippet courtesy of Firebase:

```
await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithPopup(GoogleAuthProvider());
```

Whenever I run this locally (`flutter run -d chrome`) and use my testing account that has 2-level authentication, I have to receive and enter an SMS confirmation code. This happens because each time Dart VM starts locally it uses a different port. How do I start Dart VM on a specific port to avoid dealing with SMS confirmation codes?

UPDATE: The way to do it is to run: `flutter run -d chrome --web-port 5000`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify a port number while running flutter web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58248277/how-to-specify-a-port-number-while-running-flutter-web)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do it is to run: `flutter run -d chrome --web-port 5000`